# Is it more efficient to check function props existence before calling them in React or to provide empty function as default prop for them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization

Basically I want to know what is better practice in React to assign a default prop of a callback to null and use an if statement to call It or assign It to an empty function and call It everytime.

```js
const Component = ({
  callGA=null,
  handlerClick=null,
  onClick=null,
  to='/',
  gaData={},
})=>{
  const handleComposedClick = () => {
    if (gaData) callGA(gaData, to);
    if (handlerClick) handlerClick();
    if (onClick) onClick();
  }
  return <button onClick={handleComposedClick}>...</button>
}
```

VS

```js
const Component = ({
  callGA=()=>{},
  handlerClick=()=>{},
  onClick=()=>{},
  to='/',
  gaData={},
})=>{
  const handleComposedClick = () => {
    callGA(gaData, to);
    handlerClick();
    onClick();
  }
  return <button onClick={handleComposedClick}>...</button>
}
```

Comment: Hey @David Behar as per my suggestion callback with if condition is much better then diect calling of callback function, you have to manage the code of execution by if condition.

Comment: Title says “more efficient”, but body says “better practice”. “Better practice” is definitely the better question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass a callback as a prop to a component, but only sometimes (e.g. for some instances of the component but not others), then your component should tolerate not having anything to call. There is no point creating an empty function in lieu of an actual callback just because your component needs to call *something*, when there isn't an actual reason why it has to. It could instead conditionally call the callback if it was actually provided, and not worry about it if it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

**Method-1:** If-check: (Faster)

```
const { foo } = props;
if (foo) {
  foo();
}
```

**Method-2:** Empty function as default value: (Slower)

```
const { foo = () => {} } = props;
foo();
```

**Method-1** (if-check) is **faster** (more efficient) when executed many times (~ 50+);
and **Method-2** is faster when executed few (1 or 2) times.

JS bench: https://jsbench.me/4bkdj9r61i

It is so because in Method-2, the function, empty or the passed one, gets executed *every time* whereas in Method-1 the function gets executed only *if* it is defined.

---

In a typical React application, you would not be calling the function many times, so you are good with either one.

But I would suggest to use **Method-1 (if-check)** because if will check against all **falsy** (`null`, `undefined`, `''`, `0`, `false` etc) values whereas **Method-2 (default function)** will only protect when the value isn't passed which means `undefined`.

Also, if you want to check only for `null` and `undefined` values and your toolkit supports it, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining): `foo?.()`